# Send mail via a contact form using phpmailer

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer

As I mentioned in title I want to Send mail With a contact form to gmail using phpmailer. I have written the code for my contact form and sendmail php file is given below.

I am got error on sendemail.php file in the line $mail-> Port=465;

contact.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){

$.ajax({
    url: "sendemail.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
    success: function(data){
       $('#result').html(data);
    }
});

});

});
</script>

    <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;" id ="myForm">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" name="guest_name" placeholder="Name">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" name="guest_mail" placeholder="Email address">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" name="guest_cont" placeholder="Contact No.">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" name="guest_comp" placeholder="Company Name">
          <textarea name="guest_msg" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Enquery or Feedback"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">
     </form>
```

And sendemail.php

```
<?php


    $subject = "Query/Feedback"; 
    $name = $_POST['guest_name']; 
    $email = $_POST['guest_mail']; 
    $contact = $_POST['guest_cont']; 
    $company = $_POST['guest_comp'];
    $message = $_POST['guest_msg']; 

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'rexxxxxxxxxxxxd@gmail.com';

    if($sender== '' || $mail_id== '' || $cont_no== '' || $company== '' || $msg_txt== ''){
        echo "check the fields";
    }else{

    $subject='Query from '.$sender;
    $message='Dear Sir,<br><br>'.$msg_txt.'<br><br>From: '.$sender.'<br>Contact: '.$cont_no.'<br>Company Name: '.$company;

    require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";  //including the phpmailer file

    //Installing Class
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    // Set up SMTP
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com;"
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Encoding = '7bit';

    // Authentication
    $mail->Username = "mymailid@gmail.com"
    $mail->Password = "mypassword"

    // Compose
    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['guest_mail'], $_POST['guest_name']);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['guest_mail'], $_POST['guest_name']);
    $mail->Subject = "/new Contact From Enquery"
    $mail->MsgHTML($guest_msg);

    // Send To
    $mail->AddAddress($email_to, "Banti");
    $result = $mail->Send();
    if($result)
        {
        echo "Thank you for your Feedback";
    }

    }


?>
```

Comment: Well is that port open on the server?

Comment: youre going to get someone spamming your target email address to death.  Whats to stop someone scripting a way to constantly call your ajax call?  Huge DoS attack vulnerability.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel yet again, and suffering the consequences as you are, why don't you start with known-good code, like [the gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps)?

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment yet due to my low rep, so maybe i have misunderstood the question.. but, if with "i got an error setting the Port" you mean that your PHP script runs but the email is not sent, the problem is probably that gmail needs:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
```

I use PHPMailer with gmail as well.

**Edit**

You are missing some ";" :

```
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com;" // you have this
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // you need this
$mail->Username = "mymailid@gmail.com"; // add this
$mail->Password = "mypassword"; // add this
```

Comment: this error is showing:   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$mail' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/fitweznz/public_html/sendemail1.php on line 31

Comment: Yes I Tried that its result same

Comment: You are missing the semicolons ";" also in the Authentication section. Try adding a ;  after "mymailid@gmail.com"  and after "mypassword"

Comment: mmh.. actually just a good watcher lol .. if i helped, please mark my post as the answer.